# running a python script several times using a virtual environment by means of a bash script

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I am tuning hyper parameters of a deep learning network, therefore I need to run a command iteratively trying different values. I would like to run such command using a virtual environment. I have the following script to do so:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}

#added by Anaconda3 installer
export PATH="/home/javier/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

source /home/javier/anaconda3/bin/activate AIenv


backbones=("resnet101")
gradient_clip_norms=(5 10)
learning_rates=(0.0001 0.00001 0.000001)
weight_decays=(0.001 0.0005 0.0001)
layers=('heads')

for i in "${backbones[@]}"
do
  for j in "${gradient_clip_norms[@]}"
  do
    for k in "${learning_rates[@]}"
    do
      for l in "${weight_decays[@]}"
      do
        for m in "${layers[@]}"
        do
         echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
         echo  "backbone:" $i " gradient_clip_norms:" $j " learning_rate:" $k " weight_decays:" $l "layers:" $m
         echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
         python3 custom.py train --dataset=customImages/ --weights=coco --backbone=$i --grad_clip_norms=$j --learn_rate=$k --weight_decays=$l --layers=$m
         echo "successfully done"
        done
      done
    done
  done
done
```

However, it seems is not activating the AIenv, since I run this code:

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print (str(get_python_lib()))
```

and the output is: `/home/javier/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages`
instead of `/home/javier/anaconda3/envs/AIenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

I run this command in the terminal to run the bash script (running in background as the training takes more than 2 days):

```
nohup ./run_hyper_param_tuning.sh> ../../logs/hyper_model_wed.txt 2>&1  & echo $! >save_pid.txt
```

How can I activate a virtual environment in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Instead of using the command line: `source /home/javier/anaconda3/bin/activate AIenv`

Just use: `export PATH="/home/javier/anaconda3/envs/AIenv/bin:$PATH"`

Hope it help to activate the AIenv.